# How to define a tuple for reading 4 dimensional parameter in cplex .mod file and .dat file?

Tags: excel, parameters, tuples, cplex, 4d

How can I read data 4D from Excel file for MILP model in Cplex?

I want to know how to define this parameter and apply in constraint
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn2do.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGeRd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a tuple set.

[.mod](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/read4Darray.mod)

```
range A=1..2;
range B=1..3;
range C=1..4;
range D=1..2;


tuple someTuple{
    key int a;
    key int b;
    key int c;
    key int d;
    int value;
    };
    

{someTuple} someSet = ...;

int v[a in A][b in B][c in C][d in D]=item(someSet,<a,b,c,d>).value;

dvar int X[A][B][C][D];

subject to
{
    forall(a in A,b in B,c in C,d in D) X[a][b][c][d]==v[a][b][c][d];
}


assert forall(a in A,b in B,c in C,d in D) X[a][b][c][d]==a*b*c*d;
```

[.dat](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/read4Darray.dat)

```
SheetConnection sheet("write4Darray.xlsx");

someSet from SheetRead(sheet,"A1:E48");
```

[image]

Comment: i got this error: 
Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: excel: range has a bad size. it must be only 1 line or 1 row. vmat5-10420-v3  Unknown OPL Problem Marker